# Multivitamin course duration

Tags: micronutrients, dosage

I see that multivitamin pack contains tablets for 60 days. Should I buy a new one once this finishes? I particularly ask because [one product](http://www.tervisepyramiid.ee/213/0/readmore/137) contains 1200% RDA of B12. How long can you sustain that?

Comment: I have noticed that http://health.stackexchange.com/q/788 addresses B12 specifically.

Answer (score 1):

The potential toxicity of vitamins varies enormously, but as a rough guide, fat soluble ones have a much higher potential to be stored in your body and build up to toxic levels whereas water soluble ones are likely to simply be flushed out in your urine. I would be wary of taking high doses of fat soluble vitamins over an extended period. See [here](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=10736).